# java swing mvc architecture - Q with MCVE example

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

Given multiple questions [excellent_informative_for_me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-not-working-after-rewriting-to-mvc) - [trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/4476122)'s answer, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973799/java-swing-mvc-architecture), and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445891/mvc-architecture-patterns) and several others that do not answer my question,
**how should one design classes in regard to ActionListeners location**
(and overall MVC separation - more explained below).

#### TOC

1. Question explained
2. Tree of files structure of my example (4)
3. Compile/clean commands for sources (4)
4. Sources

#### 1. question explained

I've read about MVC, and I presume I understood most of it, let us assume that is true, for the sake of this question. Not going into details:

1. View is produced from Model, on Controller request.
   In most implementations View has access to Model instance.
2. Controller interacts with user, propagates changes to Model and View.
3. Model is, in extreme simplification, container for data.
   It can be observed by View.

Now, my confusion concerns ActionListeners - which class should register - and in turn also contain - code for buttons, or in fact code for most View elements, that aren't actually just indicators, but Model manipulators?

Let's say, that we have two items in View - **button to change Model data** and some **visual item used ONLY to change View appearance**. It seems reasonable to leave code responsible for changing View appearance in View class. My question relates to first case. I had several ideas:

- View creates buttons, so it's kind of natural to create ActionListeners, and register callbacks at the same time, in View. *But this requires that View had code related to model, breaking encapsulation. View was supposed to know only little about underlying Controller or Model, talking to it via Observer only.*
- I could expose View items like buttons, etc and attach ActionListeners to them from Controller, *but this again breaks encapsulation.*
- I could implement somewhat of a callback, for each button - View would ask controller if it has any code that is supposed to be registered as ActionListener for given button name, *but this seems overly complicated, and would require synchronization of names between controller and view.*
- I could assume, being sane ;), that buttons in TableFactory might be made public, allow injecting ActionListeners to any code.
- Controller could replace whole View items (creating button and replacing existing one) *but this seems insane, as its not it's role*

#### 2. tree of files structure of my example (4)

```
.
└── test
    ├── controllers
    │   └── Controller.java
    ├── models
    │   └── Model.java
    ├── resources
    │   └── a.properties
    ├── Something.java
    └── views
        ├── TableFactory.java
        └── View.java
```

#### 3. compile/clean commands for sources (4)

Compile with:

- javac test/Something.java test/models/*.java test/controllers/*.java test/views/*.java

Run with:

- java test.Something

Clean with:

- find . -iname "*.class" -exec rm {} \;

#### 4. sources

This code contains also internationalization stub, for which I asked separate question, those lines are clearly marked and should not have any impact on answer.

Controllers => Controller.java

```
package test.controllers;
import test.models.Model;
import test.views.View;
public class Controller {
// Stub - doing nothing for now.
}
```

Models => Model.java

```
package test.models;
import java.util.Observable;
public class Model extends Observable {
}
```

Something.java

```
package test;

import test.views.View;
import test.models.Model;
import test.controllers.Controller;

public class Something {

    Model m;
    View v;
    Controller c;

    Something() {
        initModel();
        initView();
        initController();
    }

    private void initModel() {
        m = new Model();
    }

    private void initView() {
        v = new View(m);
    }
    private void initController() {
        c = new Controller(m, v);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Something it = new Something();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

View => View.java

```
package test.views;

import java.awt.*;              // layouts
import javax.swing.*;           // JPanel

import java.util.Observer;      // MVC => model
import java.util.Observable;    // MVC => model
import test.models.Model;       // MVC => model

import test.views.TableFactory;

public class View {

    private JFrame root;
    private Model model;
    public JPanel root_panel;

    public View(Model model){
        root = new JFrame("some tests");
        root.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        root_panel = new JPanel();

        root_panel.add(new TableFactory(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}));

        this.model = model;
        this.model.addObserver(new ModelObserver());

        root.add(root_panel);
        root.pack();
        root.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        root.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ModelObserver implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.print(arg.toString());
        System.out.print(o.toString());
    }
}
```

View => TableFactory.java

```
package test.views;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableFactory extends JPanel {

    private String[] cols;
    private String[] buttonNames;
    private Map<String, JButton> buttons;
    private JTable table;

    TableFactory(String[] cols){

        this.cols = cols;
        buttonNames = new String[]{"THIS", "ARE", "BUTTONS"};
        commonInit();
    }
    TableFactory(String[] cols, String[] buttons){

        this.cols = cols;
        this.buttonNames = buttons;
        commonInit();
    }

    private void commonInit(){

        this.buttons = makeButtonMap(buttonNames);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.table = new JTable(model);
        for (String col: this.cols)
            model.addColumn(col);

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel buttons_container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        for (String name : buttonNames){
            buttons_container.add(buttons.get(name));
        }

        JScrollPane table_container = new JScrollPane(table);

        this.removeAll();
        this.add(buttons_container);
        this.add(table_container);
        this.repaint();
    }

    private Map<String, JButton> makeButtonMap(String[] cols){
        Map<String, JButton>  buttons = new HashMap<String, JButton>(cols.length);
        for (String name : cols){
            buttons.put(name, new JButton(name));
        }
        return buttons;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT (in response to comments below)

---

Next informative sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288265/modifying-independent-jpanels-from-the-jframe)

After some more thought I understood Olivier's comment and later Hovercraft full of eels's details... `javax.swing.Action` => setAction was my way to go. Controller accesses View's JPanels, get's reference to map containing buttons or any JComponent, and adds action to it. View has no clue what is in Controllers code. I'll update this answer when I make it work nicely, so anyone that stumbles here might have it.

Only two things that worries me are (both pretty rare, but still):

1. since I make View's method of adding action public, actually i trust anyone to add it only from controller or view. But had the model had access to view - it could override actions too.
2. overriding, too. If I set some object's action, and then forget and set another action from different place, it's just gone, which might make debugging hard.

Comment: If you want to totally decouple Swing as view, you should create your `ActionListener`s in your view. Also, you should then think about using `javax.swing.Action` instead of `ActionListener` where possible.

Comment: The view can have ActionListeners added to JButtons, but you could have the listener simply call a Control method, or change the state of a view "bounded" property, one that on change notifies listeners to the view, by calling one of the view's property change support's notify methods. Or go @OlivierGrégoire's route and use AbstractActions, and these can be "injected" into the view via the control if need be.

Comment: Olivier - I'm not quite sure for now do I want to decouple them. Perhaps the effort is not worth in long run?
@HovercraftFullOfEels - I understand that You mentioned my 1'st bullet, and 3'rd bullet? I'm not sure if I follow exact sense of sentence starting from "change state of view bounded property" - could You please rephrase, maybe elaborate or just use somewhat simpler words?

Comment: Note, you don't "expose" buttons and what not. You expose public methods only that allow for addition of listeners or actions. Regarding "bound" properties, check the [JavaBean Properties Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html). Note that Swing GUI's have innate support for these since every Swing component has its own SwingPropertyChangeSupport field.

Comment: Wouldn't property change event also fire for example on frame and thus button resizing? And I'm wondering if that's not too much to process, such generic Action handler. I'm afraid I'm too focused on making something similar to function pointer (which doesn't exist in Java) pointing to something in Controller class which I could attach to Listener. I'll look into Beans but for now I didn't plan to go too deep into unknown packages (which java.beans is to me).

Comment: @JustMe: you only listen to the properties that you want to respond to. [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22288265/522444).

Comment: To explain it a little better: having table as above, when I attach action ADD to button, I want it to append a row to table. I haven't modified Model yet, as no data has been entered. But on row modification I want this View component change to fire action which should be handled by Controller - modifying Model (row has been updated), and then View would get refreshed, due to Observer pattern (Model onUpdate).

Comment: Consider simplifying your code, getting rid of all code not relevant to the problem at hand. For instance, there's no need for resource bundles in this question, for factory methods, and what not as they only serve to distract from the central problem. Instead you're better served by fleshing out your model and control just a little more with your own attempt.

Comment: Edit: scratch the part about TableFactory as that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

While the [Model–View–Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) pattern is [no panacea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), it *is* a recurrent pattern in Swing application design. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556585/230513), Swing control components are frequently part of the view containment hierarchy: A Swing application's controller may have little to do but connect such components to a relevant listener; instances of [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which "can be used to separate functionality and state from a component," are particularly convenient. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), the <kbd>Reset</kbd> handler, a simple `ActionListener`, is nested in the controller, but it could just as well be exported from the model as an `Action`. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259102/230513), you may have to experiment with different designs. Several approaches are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737036/230513).

Answer (score 1):

While @trashgod answer summarizes and extends to some degree discussion from comments, I'm posting, ugly (but working) solution based on that discussion (implementing Action in Controller class)

What had to change?

1. TableFactory - added `public void setObjectAction(Action a, JButton b)` and allowed public access to `Map<String, JButton> buttons`
2. Controller class needed implementation of AbstractAction or class that inherits from it, and code that sets object of this class to View's deeply nested JComponent. I find that part quite ugly, and I'm not sure if this approach is sane, or is there any better solution (will check Hovercraft full of eels Beans sometime later).
3. No additional changes were needed yet I modified View.java a little to show purpose of this question slightly better, or in different light (this makes View.java more than MCVE but IMHO describes purpose better)

#### TableFactory.java

```
package test.views;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.Action;

public class TableFactory extends JPanel {

    private String[] cols;
    private String[] buttonNames;
    public Map<String, JButton> buttons;
    private JTable table;

    TableFactory(String[] cols){
        this.cols = cols;
        buttonNames = new String[]{"some", "buttons"};
        commonInit();
    }
    TableFactory(String[] cols, String[] buttons){

        this.cols = cols;
        this.buttonNames = buttons;
        commonInit();
    }

    private void commonInit(){

        this.buttons = makeButtonMap(buttonNames);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.table = new JTable(model);
        for (String col: this.cols)
            model.addColumn(col);

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel buttons_container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        for (String name : buttonNames){
            buttons_container.add(buttons.get(name));
        }

        JScrollPane table_container = new JScrollPane(table);

        this.removeAll();
        this.add(buttons_container);
        this.add(table_container);
        this.repaint();
    }

    private Map<String, JButton> makeButtonMap(String[] cols){
        Map<String, JButton>  buttons = new HashMap<String, JButton>(cols.length);
        for (String name : cols){
            buttons.put(name, new JButton(name));
        }
        return buttons;
    }

    public void setObjectAction(Action a, JButton b){
        //it might be possible to set actions to something else than button, I imagine JComponent, but I havent figured out yet how
        b.setAction(a);
    }
}
```

#### View.java

```
package test.views;

import java.awt.*;              // layouts
import javax.swing.*;           // JPanel

import java.util.Observer;      // MVC => model
import java.util.Observable;    // MVC => model
import test.models.Model;       // MVC => model

import test.views.TableFactory;

public class View {

    private JFrame root;
    private Model model;
    public JPanel root_panel;
    public JPanel some_views[];

    public View(Model model){
        root = new JFrame("some tests");
        root.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        root_panel = new JPanel();

        some_views = new JPanel[] { 
                       new TableFactory(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}),
                       new TableFactory(new String[]{"e", "e"}) };
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        for (JPanel tab: some_views){
            String name = tab.getClass().getSimpleName();
            tabs.addTab(name, null, tab, name);
            //tab.setObjectAction(action, (JComponent) button); // can set internal 'decorative' View's action here, that are not interacting with Model
            // for example, add new (empty) row to JTable, as this does not modify Model (yet)
        }
        root_panel.add(tabs);


        this.model = model;
        this.model.addObserver(new ModelObserver());

        root.add(root_panel);
        root.pack();
        root.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        root.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ModelObserver implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.print(arg.toString());
        System.out.print(o.toString());
    }
}
```

#### Controller.java

```
package test.controllers;

import test.models.Model;
import test.views.View;


import javax.swing.Action;
import java.awt.event.*;
import test.views.TableFactory;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Controller {
    private Model model;
    private View view;
    public Controller(Model model, View view){
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        ((test.views.TableFactory)view.some_views[0]).setObjectAction(
            (Action) new ModelTouchingAction("move along, nothing here"),
            ((test.views.TableFactory)view.some_views[0]).buttons.get("FIRST") );
    }

    class ModelTouchingAction extends AbstractAction { 
        public ModelTouchingAction(String text) {
            super(text);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.print("Invoked: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Extending `AbstractAction` is `abstract`, so you _have_ to extend it. It lets controls (e.g. buttons , menus, popups and tool bars) share functionality in a consistent way.

Comment: @trashgod - You re right about abstract. About MCVE I'd be happy to do that if You're willing to point what is redundant or unnecessary in Your opinion. All of this has already been trimmed down. I am going to cut down pieces regarding internationalization, and copy them to second question, but that's about it, i find no other parts delete-able as this question mainly focuses on architecture, which also is keeping current directory structure as is.

Comment: One thing you could do is to create one file for the whole program. You could still have multiple classes in that file, but only one would be public, and that would hold the main method. Why is this important? This makes it easy to copy and paste the whole thing en toto into our IDE's, allowing us to more easily test your code.

Comment: Agreed, but this would require to redesign class permissions, as they are in different packages, with different access. But You made good point so I'll do it.

Comment: Thanks for pursuing this; I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels' rationale regarding a self-contained [mcve]; note that the controller needs to _know_ about the `Action`, but it need not _contain_ it; `Swing` text components use _package-private_ access to make relevant actions available internally.

Comment: @trashgod So I did, but in different answer, so I'll have it logically grouped. Actually this seems to have exhausted most of my questions in this question. I am thankful for all comments,  pointed me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Working version, compacted to single Something.java file.
Run with `javac Something.java && java Something`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class Controller {
    private enum TYPE { RESET, ADD, DEL };
    private Model model;
    private View view;
    public Controller(Model model, View view){
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
        ((TableFactory) view.tf).setObjectAction(
            (Action) new ModelTouchingAction("reset*",TYPE.RESET),
            "BUTTON1" );
        ((TableFactory) view.tf).setObjectAction(
            (Action) new ModelTouchingAction("add*",TYPE.ADD),
            "BUTTON2" );
        ((TableFactory) view.tf).setObjectAction(
            (Action) new ModelTouchingAction("del*",TYPE.DEL),
            "BUTTON3" );
    }

    class ModelTouchingAction extends AbstractAction {
        private TYPE t;
        public ModelTouchingAction(String text, TYPE type) {
            super(text);
            this.t = type;
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(this.t == TYPE.ADD)
                model.add();
            else if(this.t == TYPE.DEL)
                model.del();
            else
                model.reset();
        }
    }
}

class Model extends Observable {
    private ArrayList<String[]> data;
    private static int cnt = 0;
    Model(){ reset(); }
    public void reset(){
        data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        data.add(new String[]{"cell a1", "cell a2", "cell a3"});
        data.add(new String[]{"cell b1", "cell b2", "cell b3"});
        info();
    }
    public void add(){
        cnt++;
        data.add(new String[]{String.valueOf(cnt++), 
                 String.valueOf(cnt++), String.valueOf(cnt++)});
        info();
    }
    public void del(){
        if (data.size()>0){
            data.remove(data.size() - 1);
            info();
        }
    }
    private void info(){ setChanged();  notifyObservers(); }
    public ArrayList<String[]> get(){ return data; }
}

public class Something {

    Model m;
    View v;
    Controller c;
    Something() {
        initModel();
        initView();
        initController();
    }

    private void initModel() {
        m = new Model();
    }
    private void initView() {
        v = new View(m);
    }
    private void initController() {
        c = new Controller(m, v);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Something it = new Something();
            }
        });
    }
}

class View {

    private JFrame root;
    private Model model;
    public JPanel root_panel;
    public TableFactory tf;

    public View(Model model){
        root = new JFrame("some tests");
        root.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        root_panel = new JPanel();
        tf = new TableFactory(new String[]{"col1", "col2", "col3"});
        root_panel.add(tf);

        this.model = model;
        this.model.addObserver(new ModelObserver(tf));

        root.add(root_panel);
        root.pack();
        root.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        root.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ModelObserver implements Observer {
    TableFactory tf;
    ModelObserver(TableFactory tf){ this.tf = tf; }
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (null != o)
            this.tf.populate(((Model) o).get());
            // view reloads ALL from model, optimize it
            // check what to check to get CMD from Observable
        else
            System.out.print("\nobservable is null");
        if (null != arg)
            System.out.print(arg.toString());
        else
            System.out.print("\narg is null. No idea if it should be.");
    }
}

class TableFactory extends JPanel {

    private String[] cols;
    public String[] buttonNames;
    private Map<String, JButton> buttons;
    private JTable table;

    TableFactory(String[] cols){

        this.cols = cols;
        buttonNames = new String[]{"BUTTON1", "BUTTON2", "BUTTON3"};
        commonInit();
    }
    TableFactory(String[] cols, String[] buttons){

        this.cols = cols;
        this.buttonNames = buttons;
        commonInit();
    }

    private void commonInit(){

        this.buttons = makeButtonMap(buttonNames);
        DefaultTableModel tabModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.table = new JTable(tabModel);
        for (String col: this.cols)
            tabModel.addColumn(col);

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel buttons_container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        for (String name : buttonNames){
            buttons_container.add(buttons.get(name));
        }

        JScrollPane table_container = new JScrollPane(table);

        this.removeAll();
        this.add(buttons_container);
        this.add(table_container);
        this.repaint();
    }
    public void populate(ArrayList<String[]> data){
        ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).setRowCount(0);
        for(String[] row:data) addRow(row); 
    }
    private void addRow(String[] row){
        ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(row);
        // this is actually called only by populate, model does not have single 
        // row update here (and onUpdate ModelObserver cannot differentiate 
        // yet what method to call on Observable, TODO: check CMD? )
    }
    private void delRow(int rowID){
        System.out.print("\nJPanel should be deleting table row " + rowID);
    }
    public void setObjectAction(Action action, String buttonName){
        buttons.get(buttonName).setAction(action);
    }
    private Map<String, JButton> makeButtonMap(String[] cols){
        Map<String, JButton>  buttons = new HashMap<String, JButton>(cols.length);
        for (String name : cols){
            buttons.put(name, new JButton(name));
        }
        return buttons;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for a complete example; also consider letting `TYPE` values implement an interface to simplify `ModelTouchingAction`.